# Class vs Instance attribute in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop

In unit testing a class,

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

what is the rationale for setting up a class attribute (#1) instead of an instance attribute (#2)? The difference between class vs static vs instance attributes are clear to me (and are illustrated in many other SO posts), but what's not immediately obvious what the pros/cons or use-cases for each.

(1)

```
import unittest

class TestProduct(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        cls.product = Product("book", 30)
```

(2)

```
import unittest

class TestProduct(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.product = Product("book", 30)
```

Comment: There is no `set_up` method as part of the `unittest` framework. There is, however, the instance method `setUp` that will be called before every test method, and  the class method `setUpClass` that will be called *once* after the class is defined but before any of the test methods are run. If `Product` is immutable, it probably doesn't matter, but if it *is* mutable, the changes made by one test to the class attribute will be visible to subsequent tests in the same run.

Comment: "If Product is immutable, it probably doesn't matter, but if it is mutable, the changes made by one test to the class attribute will be visible to subsequent tests in the same run. " This comment was instrumental in my learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
class TestProduct(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.list_a = []
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.list_b = []

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.list_b)
        self.list_a.append(1)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.list_a)
        self.list_b.append(1)
```

`test_two` will succeed if it runs before `test_one`, because class attribute `list_a` will still be empty. But if it runs after `test_one`, it will fail because `test_one` appends a value to the shared class attribute.

`test_one`, on the other hand, will always pass because even if `test_two` runs first, because `test_one` sees a fresh empty list created by `setUp` immediately before `test_one` is called, not the list that `test_two` modified.

`setUp` is called before *every* instance method is called. `setUpClass` is only called once after the class is defined, but before any test is called.

In your example, it won't matter which you use if `Product` instances are immutable or no test method modifies the instance, because every test will see the same value whether it is defined in `setUp` or `setUpClass`. But when a shared `Product` instance is feasible, `setUpClass` is more efficient than recreating the same mutable value before every test.

Answer (score 1):

BTW the correct names for class and instance initialization methods are:

```
class TestProduct(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.product = Product("book", 30)

    def setUp(self):
        self.product = Product("book", 30)
```

The difference in that `setUp` will be invoked for each test method in `TestProduct`. It is intended to reset values of objects which could be changed by some tests. On the other hand, `setUpClass` is only invoked once before any test in `TestProduct`. It is intended for costly initialization of objects that are never changed in any test.